# Grunt Smoosher doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-smoosher

I'm new to Grunt. Using [smoosher](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-html-smoosher) in this Gruntfile, I'm trying to insert all the CSS and Javascript resources in my HTML:

```
module.exports = function ( grunt ) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        smoosher: {
            files: {
                'page1-dist.html': 'page1.html'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-html-smoosher' );

    grunt.registerTask( 'default', [ 'smoosher' ] );
};
```

But it doesn't do anything. It doesn't make any `page1-dist.html` file. This is the only output I get when running `grunt`:

```
Running "smoosher:files" (smoosher) task

Done, without errors.
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Never heard of "grunt-smoosher".. it gave me a good laugh.. just sounds so funny when you say it out loud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `grunt-html-smoosher` is what is known as a `multitask` in Grunt. Basically this means that you need to wrap your settings in a target, even if you are only specifying a single set of options. Having had a look at the source code for this plugin, at the bottom it logs that a file was created, so it is simply the config that is incorrect (as you're not getting the expected output). Therefore, your Gruntfile should look like this instead:

```
module.exports = function ( grunt ) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        smoosher: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'page1-dist.html': 'page1.html'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-html-smoosher' );

    grunt.registerTask( 'default', [ 'smoosher' ] );
};
```

You can replace `dist` with something else if you prefer.

Many Grunt tasks follow this pattern, which is useful if you have different options in a particular plugin depending on the files you want to affect, but you should keep it in mind if a plugin is not behaving in the way that you expect. Always make sure to read the documentation for Grunt plugins, you'll thank yourself for it later. :-)